# sshd_config - "Match Address <IPv6>" not matching

Tags: ssh, configuration, openssh, sshd, ipv6

### TLDR

In [sshd_config(5)](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config), this config segment:

```
Match Address fe80::/10
        PasswordAuthentication yes
```

... is not matching link-local IPv6 addresses as expected. Why and how to fix?

---

I am trying to configure `sshd` to only allow password authentication when connecting from local addresses. Otherwise public key authentication is required. This is the relevant config in `sshd_config`.

```
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys
PasswordAuthentication no

# Allow password auth on local network
Match Address 169.254.0.0/16,192.168.0.0/16
        PasswordAuthentication yes
Match Address fe80::/10
        PasswordAuthentication yes
```

#### What works:

- Public key authentication enabled on all addresses, as expected.
- Password authentication enabled on address range `169.254.0.0/16,192.168.0.0/16` when connecting via IPv4, as expected.

#### What does not work:

- Password authentication is not enabled on address range `fe80::/10` when connecting via IPv6.

[image: PuTTY Error]

Relevant line in `var/log/secure`:

```
sshd[9457]: Connection reset by fe80::39c9:9db5:5a2a:1299%eth0 port 60468 [preauth]
```

... which is an address that should be matched by `fe80::/10`

#### Checklist items I've done:

- IPv6 traffic is not blocked by firewall
- `sshd` is listening on both stacks

```
$ netstat -tupln | grep sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8903/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      8903/sshd
```

- Combining / splitting the `Match` statements for IPv4 and IPv6 does nothing
  `Match Address 169.254.0.0/16,192.168.0.0/16,fe80::/10`
  This doesn't work either.
- Putting the IPv6 address in square brackets
  `Match Address [fe80::]/10`
  No bueno.
- `sshd` does not log any config error in `var/log/secure`
- Not a client problem - tried OpenSSH, PuTTY, WinSCP and got the same error

---

#### Versions:

`sshd` running on CentOS 7

```bsh
$ uname -msr
Linux 5.4.72-v8.1.el7 aarch64
$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
```

---

I've already asked this question over on `/r/sysadmin`'s discord server, and people's reaction was "weird". See our full conversation [here](https://discord.com/channels/362843193617678337/362847933218947072/864437293283278858) if you are interested. It has some more minor details on the different things I tried.

Comment: Sorry for my previous comment. Please try to use only 1 time `Match Address 169.254.0.0/16,192.168.0.0/16,fe80::/10`, instead of 2 times. It may possible that the 2nd entry of `Match Address` is being discarded.

Comment: That was what I did originally, as I listed in the things I already tried. "Combining / splitting the Match statements for IPv4 and IPv6 does nothing"

Comment: Wait, you are trying to login via root? What value do you have for `PermitRootLogin` in your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`? Please try to login with a normal user, instead of root.

Comment: The fact that I'm trying to login as root is irrelevant here. The error is clearly about authentication method; plus I can login as root just fine as long as I'm on IPv4 and/or using public key authentication.

Comment: No, it's not irrelevant, the default login method for root ssh login is using public-key-only. You better check your value for `PermitRootLogin`.

Comment: As I said, I have no problems logging into root. Also contrary to what you said, The default for `PermitRootLogin` is `yes`. See [here](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config#:~:text=only%27%27%2C%20or%20%27%27no%27%27.-,The%20default%20is%20%27%27yes%27%27.,-If%20this%20option). And yes I set it to `yes` anyway, and it did nothing. I hope it's clear at this point this has **nothing at all** to do with what user I'm logging in as.

Comment: The default value depends on what has been compiled as default.

Comment: Could it be because you are connecting on a link local address, and the client is listed as being from fe80::39c9:9db5:5a2a:1299%eth0 which includes the interface? Maybe it would work with a non-link local address.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After trying just about everything I could think of, I was able to find a solution that worked for me. I wanted to allow password auth to users on my LAN but only allow key based auth from outside the LAN which is why I ended up finding this post.

From other reading I saw some indication that square brackets should be used with an ipv6 address and I also saw in the sshd logs that it logged the interface name (i.e. `eth0`, `wlan0`) where my connection came from when I would connect using ipv6.

I decided to test all of the combos until I found something that worked. I put in my full ipv6 address and did not use a /10 to make sure that the format of that would not interfere and I tried with and without the interface name and with and without brackets (and putting them around different parts of the address) and I can definitively say that sshd does not like the brackets. Any time I included them it did not work.

It also did not work without the interface name specified even if I used my full exact ipv6 address so it seems like sshd expects an ipv6 address to not include square brackets as it would in a URL and expects that it will include the interface name no matter what.

The last piece was the /10 to include all link local addresses. I initially expected the correct form to be `fe80::/10%eth0` but surprisingly that did not work. Instead sshd expects you to write `fe80::%eth0/10`. I guess this kind of makes sense if you view the /10 as modifying the entire ip address where a proper and complete ipv6 address is some number and an interface name while an ipv4 is only the number, but in either case, with that twist unraveled, I had a solution.

This was the full match block I used to allow ipv4 and ipv6 local connections to authenticate with passwords:

```
Match Address 10.0.0.0/8,172.16.0.0/12,192.168.0.0/16,fe80::%eth0/10
        PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Obviously you would need to modify the name `eth0` to be the correct interface name for you machine, (you can look at the list of them with `ifconfig` or check the sshd logs when you attempt to connect via ipv6 to see what interface your connection is using) and If you wanted to support connections from multiple interfaces I think you need to specify `,fe80::%name/10` for each one.

I hope this answer helps others who stumble upon this thread (and maybe OP, though I am not sure how much help this will be five months later)

Comment: OP here. Thanks for this very detailed answer - such answers are never too late. The servers in question are my personal servers, and the entire reason I wanted to have such a configuration is so that I don't get locked out in case I lost all my private keys in some terrible accident. I will be applying this configuration this weekend; your effort is very much appreciated!

Comment: I had the same problem and your solution worked, but because I was using a NAT with port forwarding, external IPs were still able to connect as SSH just saw the local router IP... So be careful!